# Static bundling from a remote url in webpack

Tags: webpack

This seems like a really simple question and have searched for an answer, but all the answers are about *dynamically* loading a remote url.

I have a need to bundle libraries that are published as raw (non-NPM) source in Github. I would like webpack to download and include these files in my bundle. Caching the file locally for a period of time would be a bonus.

For example, I would like to be able to write:

```
const mylib=require("http://www.espruino.com/modules/ADNS5050.min.js");
```

And have webpack download and include this js file statically. The bundle is going to be pushed to an embedded device that doesn't have any networking!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something basic working using a function in `externals`, like this...

```
npm install --save-dev fetch
```

... webpack config ...

```
var fetchUrl = require('fetch').fetchUrl;
module.exports = {
...
    externals: function(context, request, callback) {
        if ( request.indexOf('http') === 0 ) {
            fetchUrl(request, function(error, meta, body){
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
                callback(null, body.toString());
            });
            return;
        }
        switch (request) {
            // these are provided on the target platform
            case 'PCD8544':
            case 'Flash':
                return callback(null, 'require("'+request+'")');
        }
        // default
        callback();
    },
...
}
```

Just need to add some basic caching when running `webpack --watch`!

Comment: I tried to write a very simple loader, but webpack wants to resolve the resource before calling the loader, and obviously can't do this with a url.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the other post: I have looked around for a solution and most of all proposals were based on externals, which is not valid in my case. I finished using a separate JS file which is responsible for downloading the desired file into a local directory. Then WebPack scans this directory and bundles the downloaded files together with the application.

See the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62603539/8650621

Answer (score 0):

The `webpack-require-http` plugin should meet your needs.

Or try `scriptjs`:

```
var $script = require("scriptjs");
$script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
  $('body').html('It works!')
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I believe both of these are async loaders that defer the load until after the bundle is built, ie. urls are resolved at runtime. I want to resolve the url at build time.

Comment: Have you tested and confirmed this?